# Correspondence Analysis in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a Correspondence Analysis in R, with ca library but I get the following error:

```
Error in svd(S) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

`In addition: Warning message:`

`In sqrt(eP) : NaNs produced`

This is my dataset

```
                  Dif_Aud Dif_Alc Dif_Shr     Dif_Ats
DKIDS              -17307 -105249   0.361 -2.26666666
CARTOON            -14583 -132158   0.430  2.16666666
SPORTV             -23820 -208902  -0.796 -1.53333333
MULTISHOW            3869  -30392   1.770  4.61666667
MEGAPIX            -11683 -129625   0.086 -0.43333333
FOX                -25429 -185373  -1.413 -7.56666666
TNT                -12390 -116205  -0.250 -3.75000000
SPACE               -7121  -89169   0.164 -0.43333333
VIVA                -4720  -75378   0.390  0.86666667
DISNEY             -14668  -96903  -0.644 -7.95000000
TC PREMIUM            675   25897   0.837 -1.98333333
UNIVERSAL          -12952 -104380  -0.569 -6.55000000
TC PIPOCA            2017   51298   0.934 -4.30000000
AXN                 -6406  -60997   0.062 -0.90000000
DISCOVERY CHANNEL   -7080  -86041  -0.029 -1.60000000
GNEWS               -2457  -89800   0.408  4.76666667
FX                 -12896 -143305  -0.663 -2.13333334
GNT                 -1915  -75992   0.365  4.31666666
TC ACTION             103   13328   0.544 -2.25000000
NICK                -5392  -61935  -0.018 -0.06666666
SPORTV_2            -4223  -83112   0.085  0.55000000
WARNER              -6717  -68173  -0.218 -4.10000000
H&H                 -9809 -119686  -0.550  1.53333333
ANIMAL               1172  -21680   0.507  5.35000000
NATGEO              -7404 -127921  -0.356 -1.10000000
ESPN BR             -2676  -18278   0.060 -4.20000000
CINEMAX             -5028  -96745  -0.180 -0.68333333
FOX SPORTS         -10027  -73034  -0.709 -7.33333333
SONY                -3979  -58269  -0.118 -2.25000000
HISTORY             -8792 -110035  -0.608 -4.10000000
BOOMERANG           -5084  -62047  -0.253 -0.93333334
TC FUN              -3711  -36152  -0.129 -4.98333333
HBO                  1088   22788   0.317  1.28333334
SPORTV 3            -2948  -95394  -0.093  0.68333334
FOX Life            -2286  -52071  -0.034  5.83333334
GLOOB               -6703  -73867  -0.482 -6.26666667
TLC                 -5305  -75255  -0.352 -2.90000000
DISNEY XD           -4517  -51180  -0.292 -5.06666667
A&E                 -4565  -84667  -0.306  0.26666667
MTV                 -4399  -67367  -0.325 -2.48333334
```

When i run svd in this object

```
> svd(analise)
$d
[1] 586218.63825  21265.02168     37.52027     16.15292      2.09432

$u
             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
 [1,]  0.18150580 -0.35027170  0.121797235  0.20447594  0.384868406
 [2,]  0.22677778 -0.10510095  0.143836533  0.28852816  0.284867160
 [3,]  0.35858927 -0.20212370  0.138182724  0.21491424 -0.139866059
 [4,]  0.05100616  0.31400723  0.171410051 -0.02997187  0.540177937
 [5,]  0.22201573  0.01961012  0.078690335  0.04468443  0.116447686
 [6,]  0.31888129 -0.38031298  0.096648971 -0.01609187 -0.312133863
 [7,]  0.19933447 -0.07215610  0.042661241 -0.08183358  0.031594719
 [8,]  0.15257935  0.05636619  0.097778029 -0.03556821  0.066439422
 [9,]  0.12877513  0.10850103  0.112478175 -0.01871585  0.112140330
[10,]  0.16691197 -0.26319170 -0.009717159 -0.17637196 -0.016410347
[11,] -0.04409211 -0.08159895  0.275621286 -0.21061595  0.161254500
[12,]  0.17933927 -0.15016090 -0.044239995 -0.16177399 -0.004591287
[13,] -0.08744755 -0.12979959  0.281822798 -0.34298422  0.203065145
[14,]  0.10461689 -0.03330469  0.041209263  0.01183071  0.086216607
[15,]  0.14726006  0.04461236 -0.012883596 -0.04962331  0.082898454
[16,]  0.15291151  0.27750226  0.085394175  0.10865458  0.061302591
[17,]  0.24544303  0.02261448 -0.131671500  0.04754004 -0.026167394
[18,]  0.12937320  0.24252074  0.184695518  0.04960557 -0.048427775
[19,] -0.02265344 -0.05343815  0.198548356 -0.20309772  0.093648877
[20,]  0.10604926  0.01827305 -0.067679470  0.07265230  0.120310236
[21,]  0.14183223  0.16557921  0.026622370 -0.03989230  0.025396062
[22,]  0.11685437 -0.01649793 -0.052915136 -0.15331633  0.047792910
[23,]  0.20483755  0.06390800 -0.134978543  0.22219876 -0.029791010
[24,]  0.03663682  0.14964563  0.380769937  0.04887125 -0.181505291
[25,]  0.21844303  0.21251250 -0.092643024 -0.08459933 -0.041012944
[26,]  0.03146882 -0.04539684  0.128353670 -0.26946049 -0.033165280
[27,]  0.16511501  0.18748156 -0.001570025 -0.11028449 -0.067216665
[28,]  0.12563546 -0.15022985 -0.251560894 -0.14310074  0.085496472
[29,]  0.09959864  0.06840724  0.039239453 -0.16328892 -0.053525914
[30,]  0.18828443  0.06933826 -0.146343748 -0.14252305 -0.047378800
[31,]  0.10619065  0.03318379 -0.023171971 -0.01634178 -0.039357164
[32,]  0.06199126 -0.01572483  0.025775411 -0.27846041 -0.020303504
[33,] -0.03887708 -0.04867093  0.444702495 -0.11073835 -0.267501226
[34,]  0.16249057  0.27896568  0.092346466 -0.14899540 -0.168317704
[35,]  0.08880311  0.12058372  0.199176919  0.22020238 -0.219093227
[36,]  0.12652320  0.00904771 -0.196233272 -0.23869870  0.053669639
[37,]  0.12865898  0.08057232 -0.112181262 -0.12636002 -0.008495483
[38,]  0.08764355  0.01222865 -0.152791143 -0.20826849  0.071518275
[39,]  0.14452757  0.15636344 -0.103095883  0.01313241 -0.032957984
[40,]  0.11511785  0.08851215 -0.064381624 -0.13734630 -0.055181864

$v
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
[1,] -2.161539e-05  1.969082e-04  9.783142e-01 -2.007724e-01 -5.090993e-02
[2,] -9.295601e-02  9.956700e-01 -3.248368e-04 -5.870256e-04 -3.671252e-05
[3,] -9.956702e-01 -9.295601e-02  5.866027e-06  4.406851e-05  2.142571e-06
[4,] -2.624744e-06  5.694367e-05  5.303213e-02  5.202400e-03  9.985793e-01
[5,] -1.532831e-05  6.408762e-04  2.002221e-01  9.796239e-01 -1.573699e-02
```

Then dput

```
dput(analise)
structure(list(Dif_Aud = c(-17307, 
-14583, -23820, 3869, -11683, -25429, -12390, -7121, -4720, -14668, 
675, -12952, 2017, -6406, -7080, -2457, -12896, -1915, 103, -5392, 
-4223, -6717, -9809, 1172, -7404, -2676, -5028, -10027, -3979, 
-8792, -5084, -3711, 1088, -2948, -2286, -6703, -5305, -4517, 
-4565, -4399), Dif_Alc = c(-105249, -132158, -208902, -30392, 
-129625, -185373, -116205, -89169, -75378, -96903, 25897, -104380, 
51298, -60997, -86041, -89800, -143305, -75992, 13328, -61935, 
-83112, -68173, -119686, -21680, -127921, -18278, -96745, -73034, 
-58269, -110035, -62047, -36152, 22788, -95394, -52071, -73867, 
-75255, -51180, -84667, -67367), Dif_Shr = c(0.361, 0.43, -0.796, 
1.77, 0.0860000000000003, -1.413, -0.25, 0.164, 0.39, -0.644, 
0.837, -0.569, 0.934, 0.0620000000000003, -0.0289999999999999, 
0.408, -0.663, 0.365, 0.544, -0.018, 0.085, -0.218, -0.55, 0.507, 
-0.356, 0.0600000000000001, -0.18, -0.709, -0.118, -0.608, -0.253, 
-0.129, 0.317, -0.093, -0.034, -0.482, -0.352, -0.292, -0.306, 
-0.325), Dif_Ats = c(-2.26666666000001, 2.16666666, -1.53333333, 
4.61666667, -0.43333333, -7.56666666, -3.75, -0.43333333, 0.866666670000001, 
-7.95, -1.98333333, -6.55, -4.3, -0.899999999999999, -1.6, 4.76666667, 
-2.13333334, 4.31666666, -2.25, -0.0666666599999992, 0.550000000000001, 
-4.1, 1.53333333, 5.35, -1.1, -4.2, -0.68333333, -7.33333333, 
-2.25, -4.1, -0.933333340000001, -4.98333333, 1.28333334, 0.683333340000001, 
5.83333334, -6.26666667, -2.9, -5.06666667, 0.266666669999999, 
-2.48333334)), .Names = c("Dif_Aud", "Dif_Alc", "Dif_Shr", 
"Dif_Ats"), row.names = c("DKIDS", "CARTOON", "SPORTV", "MULTISHOW", 
"MEGAPIX", "FOX", "TNT", "SPACE", "VIVA", "DISNEY", "TC PREMIUM", 
"UNIVERSAL", "TC PIPOCA", "AXN", "DISCOVERY CHANNEL", "GNEWS", 
"FX", "GNT", "TC ACTION", "NICK", "SPORTV_2", "WARNER", "H&H", 
"ANIMAL", "NATGEO", "ESPN BR", "CINEMAX", "FOX SPORTS", "SONY", 
"HISTORY", "BOOMERANG", "TC FUN", "HBO", "SPORTV 3", "FOX Life", 
"GLOOB", "TLC", "DISNEY XD", "A&E", "MTV"), class = "data.frame")
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can possibly going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some of the code where you call svd? And what is eP in this example?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @Cleb. I don't know what eP is. I edited the original post with the code after I call svd.

Comment: the results of `svd(analise)` are not helpful, we don't know what analise is. Could you post `dput(S)` ?

Comment: 'analise' is the dataset

Comment: Then what's svd(S)? And you're getting results for svd(analise)

Comment: When i call ca(analise), I get that error message with svd(S). I don't know what It means.

Comment: Ah - then post `dput(analise)`

Comment: Thanks @Señor O, I edited the original post with dput(analise) output.

Comment: I don't know much about correspondence analysis, but it looks like it's meant for frequency data, which this clearly is not? It's the fact that `sum(analise)` is negative that messes everything up. Note `ca(abs(analise))` works fine.

Comment: Can you even run a CA on data that contains negative values? We certainly don't allow it in our implementation in **vegan**. The transformations involved would indicate to me that you just can't do this.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you suggest another approach for that kind of data? Those differences are really important. I mean, there's a meaning when negative or positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a CA on data with negative values like the data set you show. The original method was for non-negative frequency/count data such as you might find in contingency tables.

We don't allow CA to be fitted to data that have non positive row sums in the **vegan** package for example. Likewise column sums need to be positive. And hence the grand sum also needs to be positive and those three sums are used to weight the data as part of the CA.

Your data clearly don't meet the requirements of the method.

Instead, consider PCA, though you'll need to standardise the input data otherwise the variables with large values will tend to dominate the ordination as they will tend to have larger variances.